# How do I replace white space(%20) to under score(_) in .htaccess ? (php based)

Tags: .htaccess

How do I replace white space(%20) to under score(_) in  .htaccess ? (php based)

```
RewriteRule "^(\S*) +(\S* .*)$" $1-$2 [N,NE]
RewriteRule "^(\S*) (\S*)$" $1-$2 [L,R=302,NE]
```

this swaps the white space to hyphen i think, but i don't know how to swap with underscore

Comment: I think i got it...                                  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\s(.*)$ /$1_$2 [L,R=301]

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\s(.*)$ /$1_$2 [L,R=301]
```

This code will match the space in the URL and replace it with an underscore